# Rails Routes: Devise Usernames with multiple dots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, devise, routes

I am running into issues where the incorrect id is passed to a controller when a username has multiple dots

For example, when loading the path="/users/rong.xu.wh06"

It passes the id  Parameters: {"id"=>"rong.xu"}

This is what I have in my routes:

```
resources :users, :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.\+]+?/ do
```

How do I resolve this issue?

By the way, the username was created from an existing email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating my routes:

```
resources :users, :id => /[^\/]+/  do
```

Comment: be careful! I realized very soon afterward this caused some issues with loading json pages (.json)